# JPQL for One to Many Relationship

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm trying to create a JPQL for one to many relationship, namely user and device as 1 user can have one to many devices. I want to find the whole object of the device if it is owned by the user and the device name is correct.

If it is a SQL query then I can just do the query only for the device as follow:

```
select * from DEVICE where USER_ID = 2 and DEVICENAME = "mypc";
```

where USER_ID is the foreign key in DEVICE table. But how can I do the JPQL query for the user and device table? Here are some info for User and Device class

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
public int id;
public String username;
public String firstname;
public String lastname;
public String hashPassword;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
public List<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();


}

@Entity
public class Device {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public int id;
    public String deviceName;
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;
    String deviceOS;
    String deviceType;
    String attributes;
    boolean standard;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you read documentation about JPQL? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-implicit-join

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example JPA Query:[Documention](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-implicit-join)

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT di FROM Device di JOIN di.user u WHERE u.id=:userId and di.deviceName=:deviceName");
query.setParameter("userId",userId );
query.setParameter("deviceName",deviceName);
List<Device> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: I follow your query but it seems to give no result whatsoever. Does it necessary to do join fetch?

Comment: You don't necessary to 'fetch' . But This query ensures that User object is in Device object.

Comment: It still doesn't give the result. Here are the result:
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-02-20 14:38:31.054--ServerSession(876563773)--Connection(966739377)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT t1.ID, t1.ATTRIBUTES, t1.DEVICENAME, t1.DEVICEOS, t1.DEVICETYPE, t1.PUBLICKEY, t1.STANDARD, t1.USER_ID, t0.ID, t0.FIRSTNAME, t0.HASHPASSWORD, t0.LASTNAME, t0.USERNAME, t0.DEPARTMENT_DEPARTMENTID FROM DEVICE t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN USER t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.USER_ID) WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND (t1.DEVICENAME = ?))
 bind => [2, FB10H117WS07]

Comment: I am not sure why but it seems now it runs fine with the new SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JPQL path expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_path) in your query to navigate from one entity to another, or to refer to attributes of an entity.

More specifically, path expressions are useful to navigate along `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne`relationships, e.g.:

```
SELECT d FROM Device d WHERE d.user.id = :userId AND d.deviceName = :deviceName
```

Here, `d.user.id` is a path expression.

For a general overview of JPQL, have a look at the great [Wikibooks article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL).

Comment: I follow your query but it also seems to give no result. Does the query need to follow the structure of the database or the POJO class itself? Because the POJO class does not have the user ID as it is foregin key.

Comment: In JPQL queries you use attributes of Entities/POJOs. The database schema doesn't matter. Your `Device` entity has a `user` attribute, which allows you to write `d.user` to navigate from `Device` to its `User`. In `User`, in turn, you have the `id` attribute, so you can write `d.user.id`. Make sure there is actually an entity in the database that satisfies your conditions (id and deviceName), and follow the answer by @jackk for fetching the query results.

Comment: I followed @jackk answer and it seems working now, but I think theoritically it should work with your answer. Anyway thanks!

Comment: If you are curious, you could also try named parameters. I've edited my answer accordingly. This should work with the answer by @jackk.