# How to query specific columns in one to many relationship - Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have 2 classes

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "age")
        private String age;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        private List<Address> addresses= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "address_id")
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "actualAddress")
        private String actualAddress;

        @Column(name = "code")
        private String code;

        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;

}
```

I need to get a list of User that has a list of Address in each user. The problem is if I do the sql like this:

```
@Query("select u from User where u.id = :userId")
List<User> getUserAndAddress(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

Hibernate will get all of Address fields because of the onetomany relationship, any idea how to write sql query to get the user list that only contain the Addresses that have id and code? I am using JPA and postgres. Thank you the net!

Comment: There are few issues in the code. The most problematic is `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` on User - this says that id of user in table Address should be saved in column id. This then can cause weird conflicts. Also, string as id? Is this expected? Coul/d you share sample contents of the DB (for few entities)?

Comment: @Pistolnikus thanks for your response, "The most problematic is @JoinColumn(name = "id") on User - this says that id of user in table Address should be saved in column id" yes I didn't notice when I wrote this down, updated properly. 
String as id is fine, it doesn't mater actually. If you have further solution for my question, please let me know, thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPQL for One to Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303746/jpql-for-one-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

To query specific columns in a one-to-many relationship using Spring Data JPA, you typically fetch the parent entity and then navigate through its collection of child entities.

Let's assume you have two entities: Parent and Child, where Parent has a one-to-many relationship with Child.

Using JPQL

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p.name, c.name FROM Parent p JOIN p.children c WHERE p.id = :parentId")
    List<Object[]> findSpecificColumnsByParentId(@Param("parentId") Long parentId);
}
```

Using Query Methods

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
    List<Parent> findById(Long parentId);
    @Query("SELECT p.name, c.name FROM Parent p JOIN p.children c WHERE p.id = :parentId")
    List<Object[]> findSpecificColumnsByParentId(@Param("parentId") Long parentId);
}
```

Comment: Does this mean we are not able to get the exact entity we want but only Object[] and we have to do the object convert ourselves? Hopefully you can share how did you manage the object converting as well. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Address mapping seems problematic, but I'll skip it.

There are several ways. I will show you how to use one of them, DTO.
First, create a DTO class with the fields you want.

```
private List<UserQueryDTO> findUsers(String userId) {
   return em.createQuery("select new your.package.path.UserQueryDTO(u.id, a.code) from 
   Address a join a.user u where u.id = :userId, OrderQueryDTO.class)
   .setParameter("userId", 
   userId)
   .getResultList();
}
```

This is a simple way to use the entity manager.
if you want, u can use querydsl or etc.

This method returns only the needed field as a DTO. I hope it will be of help.

Comment: Thank you @soonhankwon, I dont think the query is applicable to my question. I put the "code" field in Address object but u write u.code and u presents User so I am quite confusing how does it work.

Comment: I'm sorry. There was a mistake.
It has been modified to operate normally if @ManyToOne User user is in the Address Entity.

In general, it is convenient to use FK in the Many side of an association relationship.

Comment: Hi @soonhankwon, that looks good for ManyToOne relationship, but I think query OneToMany in my case should be a little bit more tricky because we have to get a list of Address for each User instead of just normal fields. Hope you can share your way on how to do OneToMany, thank you!